# For Apache listening on port 81 - "The requested URL / was not found on this server"

Tags: apache, nginx, debian, http-status-code-404

Debian 6, nginx and Apache (port 81). Domain opening falls with a 404 error:

> Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache2 configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:81 >
    ServerName domain.com
    AssignUserID user user
    CustomLog /var/www/httpd-logs/domain.com.access.log combined
    DocumentRoot /var/www/user/data/www/domain.com
    ErrorLog /var/www/httpd-logs/domain.com.error.log

    ServerAdmin info@domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5 .phtml
    AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

    php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/user/data:."
    php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f info@domain.com"
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir "/var/www/user/data/mod-tmp"
    php_admin_value session.save_path "/var/www/user/data/mod-tmp"
</VirtualHost>
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open */etc/apache2/ports.conf* and replace

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1:81
```

with

```
NameVirtualHost *:81
```

In my case, 81 is the Apache port.